# Adding total numbers(Grand Total) in pivot chart

Tags: excel, pivot

I need help in adding the total numbers on pivot table as in the picture below. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

I have tried everything but was not able to make it reflected on the chart.

Regards

Comment: If this is a pivotchart I don't think it is possible. You can't edit the legend and you can't use a formula for an item or field name in a pivot table report.

Comment: we have a chance to change any data on a list without pivot. I just need to sum all the numbers and put in in front of the total. I even ok if it is possible to make it before adding pivot chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way that I can think of is not very elegant but it should do what you want. Create a formula in a cell that gets data you need from the pivot table, it should be ok to just write in "=" and click on the cell and Excel should write down the GETPIVOTDATA formula for you. After that you just create a text box and write "=(adress of the cell) in the formula bar while you have the text box selected.

Hope that helps

Comment: just use sum function in that way ?

Comment: You can use the SUM function, or you use GETPIVOTDATA to get the sum from your pivot table, whatever works better for you.

Comment: Why on earth didn't I think of that!